# Fabric.js to Imagick (php)

Tags: php, fabricjs, imagick

I am using a custom product tool that is built around Fabric.js (FancyProductDesigner) I have needed to recreate what I made with Fabric.js (Views are stored in a database table), and re-make it using imagick for printing / previewing purposes by the factory, without needing to store each of the high definition images on the server. Since we make about 400 of these custom products on average a day, if I stored each one it would be about 160Mb a day of space to store them, and we want to store them for our customers for a minimum of 90 days after the purchase.

I have managed to recreate the entirety of the product, using PHP / Imagick, except for one thing, if someone adds text to the page, with an angle, the angle is not working with the x/y coordinates passed by Fabric.js, I have tried to work with the originX/originY settings and it doesn't seem to have any affect.

Below is the code:

```
$print = new Imagick();
$print->setResolution(72, 72);
$print->newImage(894, 765, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
foreach ($printData[0]->elements as $i => $object) {
  if($object->type == 'image'){
    $img = $object->source;
    $src = new Imagick($img);

    $size = $src->getImageGeometry();

    $resizeWidth = ($object->parameters->width * $object->parameters->scaleX);
    $resizeHeight = ($object->parameters->height * $object->parameters->scaleY);
    $src->resizeImage($resizeWidth, $resizeHeight, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
    $sizeAfterResize = $src->getImageGeometry();

    if($object->parameters->flipX){
        $src->flopImage();
    }

    if($object->parameters->flipY){
        $src->flipImage();
    }

    if($object->parameters->angle > 0){
      $src->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('transparent'), $object->parameters->angle);
      $sizeAfterRotate = $src->getImageGeometry();
    }

    if($object->parameters->fill != ''){
      $color = new ImagickPixel($object->parameters->fill);

      $opacityColor = new ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)");
      $src->colorizeImage($color, $opacityColor);
    }


    $src->evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, $object->parameters->opacity, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

    $left = $object->parameters->left;
    $top = $object->parameters->top; 

    $left= ($left-($resizeWidth/2));
    $top = ($top-($resizeHeight/2));

    $print->compositeImage($src, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $left, $top);
  } else {
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $color = new ImagickPixel($object->parameters->fill);
    $foundFont = false;
    foreach($fonts as $name => $file){
        if($name == $object->parameters->fontFamily){
          $draw->setFont('fonts/custom/ttf/'.$file);
        $foundFont = true;
        continue;
      }
    }
    if(!$foundFont) $draw->setFont('fonts/'.$object->parameters->fontFamily.'.ttf');

    $draw->setFontSize($object->parameters->fontSize);
    //$draw->setFontSize(32);
    $draw->setFontWeight(($object->parameters->fontWeight == 'bold') ? 600 : 100 );
    $draw->setFontStyle(0);
    $draw->setFillColor($color);
    $draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
    $draw->setTextAntialias(true);
    //$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
    $draw->setTextAlignment(Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);


    if($object->parameters->stroke){
      $draw->setStrokeColor($object->parameters->stroke);
      $draw->setStrokeWidth($object->parameters->strokeWidth);
      $draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);  //try with and without
    }

    $metrics = $print->queryFontMetrics($draw, $object->parameters->text);

    $realleft = round($object->parameters->left);
    $realtop = round($object->parameters->top);

    $top = $realtop;
    $left = $realleft;

    $print2 = new Imagick();
    $print2->setResolution(72, 72);

    $print2->newImage(894, 765, new ImagickPixel('#00000000'));
    $print2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND );

    $print2->annotateImage($draw, $left, $top, $object->parameters->angle, $object->parameters->text);

    if($object->parameters->flipX == 1) $print2->flopImage(); // x
    if($object->parameters->flipY == 1) $print2->flipImage(); // y

    $print2->trimImage(0);
    $print2->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0); 

    $d = $print2->getImageGeometry();

    $left-=($d['width']/2);
    $top-=($d['height']/2);

    $print->compositeImage($print2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $left, $top);
  }
}
```

I had to add the text into an image, and then add that image to the element due to a few features that I was not able to locate for text such as flip and flop. If there is no angle on the text element, the images are perfectly recreated between Fabric.js and Imagick.

[image: Results from Fabric.js]
Expectation

[image: Results from Imagick]
Reality

If you look at it you can see that the rotation causes the text to be in a different location between Imagick and Fabric.js This problem is more noticeable on some fonts than others.

I could be missing something really easy, but I just can't see it and it's driving me mad. For now I have just disabled the ability to rotate text on the design tools, however that is not a perfect solution.

Just to clarify this is not a duplicate of [PHP/Imagick: How to crate a large ( High Quality 300dpi ) image from JSON / array of Data ( width,height,x,y,angels) using PHP ImageMagic / Imagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778396/php-imagick-how-to-crate-a-large-high-quality-300dpi-image-from-json-arra?rq=1), that does not address angle issues with adding text.

Comment: Even if it's not a duplicate, I'd still recommend grabbing the SVG and using ImageMagick directly to do the conversion. That would allow you to start identifying the exact bit where your code is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I am using ImageMagick to do the conversion and the angle is the only part that is having problems, apparently the way ImageMagick angles text is not identical to how Fabric.js and/or Canvas does it.

Comment: @CoryEvans Did you ever find a solutions for this? I have been trying to resolve the same issue with Imagick adding angled text to an image differently than fabric js does. hoping you ran across a solution at some point?